# Nest PIN auth with no GUI

Tags: embedded, nest-api, mbed

I'm trying to understand exactly how the PIN-based auth on the Nest API is working.

Currently I have plans to connect a embedded platform (such as mbed) to the Nest API to use the Nest data to control some other home automation, but since the device will not contain any GUI at all I'm wondering how the PIN-based auth will work?

Is it even possible to get access to the Nest API with a device with no GUI to display PIN / enter login information ?

Regards
- Renejos

Answer (score 0):

The user is supposed to go to the following link (you may create a website that can direct user to this specific link)

https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id=CLIENT_ID&state=STATE

After user logs in and grants permissions, PIN will be shown.

Now, comes the difficult part, since your embedded system will not have GUI or any way to input.

It would be highly recommended if you could provide a simple display and buttons to enter data (A-Z and 0-9). A simple UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT buttons will suffice (Only 8 characters for user to scroll through).

If that's not possible then you will need to have a server with some device mapping with user account, where user can provide the PIN code after granting access. And AUTH CODE can then be forwarded to the device for storage and later use.